# euler lagrange and gradient descent in level set

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, optimization, partial-differential-equations

the problem began when i read the paper 
"Active Contours Without Edges"  http://www.math.ucla.edu/~lvese/PAPERS/IEEEIP2001.pdf

my trouble in equation(9) on page5 derived from page4.

At that time,i can't understand how author derive this equation.
afterward i know author use euler-lagrange and gradient descent methods,
but there are something still upset me...

(1)why we can use the result of euler-lagrange to be the gradient?

(2)why there is a parameter "t" appear in the equation(9),it doesn't appear in Page4 eqution.

i have found many papers in internet,but i still can't understand the reasons.
i'm sorry for my poor english,and i hope that i have showed my question completely.
thank you!